# How do I allow clicks to bubble up in onTouchEvent

Tags: android, touch-event

I have a ViewPager that can contain two types of views. One of the view types has buttons, one of the view types does not. The buttonless view type does have to trap touches in onTouchEvent in order to pan and zoom an image. But I want to let clicks bubble to the ViewPager (that has a clickListener attached to it)

I have to return true in the view's onTouchEvent ACTION_DOWN or else it won't see future events.

I can't use onInterceptTouchEvent() in the ViewPager to capture clicks because one of the views does have buttons and those buttons need their clicks

So how can my view trap swipes, and let clicks bubble up?

Answer (score 1):

proper way is probably to intercept only the events you want to intercept, by returning true in onInterceptTouchEvent only when needed.

but if you want to go with the dark side, there's a dirty alternative, that probably will lure you and you'll probably regret later: intercept all the events, then if needed pass them down.

e.g. have inside your views something like

```
     public boolean canInterceptTouch(MotionEvent ev) {
       // return true if you are interested in this touch event, e.g. it falls into
       // a clickable area
}
```

and something that handle the touch event like

```
    public void interceptTouch(MotionEvent ev) {
       // here you react to the event
}
```

inside your viewpager you have

```
 @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        return true;
    }
```

thien the view pager will handle the events in a dirty way like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    if (yourView.canInterceptTouch(ev))) {
            yourView.interceptTouch(ev);
            return true;
    } else {
         return doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

note: although I've done something similar, with decent result, I do NOT reccomend it as a solution unless you've very simple logic in the handling of the motion events, otherwise it becomes a mess. Your future self will be happier if you spend some time now to do it properly.

EDIT: code has not been tested, just to give you an idea of what you need. Sorry for any typo.

Comment: I love future me and would never purposely do something to annoy him.  But I think that you gave me a hint... I was doing this backwards. I should intercept everything that I want, and let the click go through. No, Damn, only ViewGroup has an onIntercept. No good.

Comment: let's put it this way. onitercepttouch here receives the events. if you return false, they keep on passing here but are dispatched to the subview. if you return true, event will go to the viewpager ontouchevent.
I had to read the doc at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
 a few times to understand how this is supposed to work, and in the meantime I was already on the Dark Side...

Comment: Ok, now that I am sitting at my desk and can see this better... It's actually what I am taking out :)
I would prefer that the container not need to know details so that I can reuse the view elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)`.This allows a ViewGroup to watch events as they are dispatched to child Views`

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I can't do that. But thanks for taking the time :)

Comment: try using a interface and implement them.